# Removing in a for loop - JAVA

Tags: java, list, loops, for-loop, arraylist

So lets say I have a for loop that is iterating through a string list. 
The string list is something like

```
List<String> myString = {NEW ROW, cs, 1, 2, 3, NEW ROW, tp, 3, 4, 5}
```

I want the for loop to iterate through the list and remove NEW ROW and the next x elements after each time NEW ROW appears in the list.

How can I do this?

My Attempt:

```
 for (int index = 0; index < myList.size(); index++) {

        if (myList.get(index).equals("NEW ROW")) {
            for (int j = index; j < index + x; j++) {
                myList.remove(j);
            }
            index = index + x;

        } 
    }
```

My attempt did not work.

Comment: Normally you're expected to say what happened with your attempt.  Did it do the wrong thing?  Did it throw an exception?  If so, what are the exception details?

Comment: this will not work, you will have to use an `iterator` since you are not allowed to remove from a list while going through the list

Comment: @jgr208 this will work because he is not iterating the list; he's using direct access

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use list iterator to simplify your code, and avoid doing index math altogether:

```
for (Iterator<String> iterator = myString .iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String string = iterator.next();
    if (string.equals("NEW ROW")) {
        // Call iterator.remove() x times,
        // or until the list runs out of elements
        for (int i = 0 ; iterator.hasNext() && i != x ; i++) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

This would work for a `LinkedList` implementation. If you use `ArrayList` implementation, you would be better off doing it all in a single loop:

```
int read = 0, write = 0;
while (read < myList.size()) {
    String s = myList.get(read);
    if (s.equals("NEW ROW")) {
        read += x;
    } else {
        myList.set(write++, s);
        read++;
    }
}
// Trim the end of the list
for (int last = myList.size()-1 ; last >= write ; last--) {
    myList.remove(last);
}
```

This implementation moves the items that you want to keep to the beginning of the list, and then trims off the end elements.

Comment: But he's using direct access, so he doesn't need an iterator to remove

Comment: @Bohemian There's no question OPs approach can be fixed with a little arithmetic: plus `x` here, minus one there, and so on. But using "Repeat `x` times or until the list runs out of data" is simpler to read.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it's always better to check for equality with the constant at the beginning, so you won't get a NPE in case the value is indeed `null`

Answer (score 3):

You just don't remove elements from lists...you are not allowed to modify data structures. OK you are but don't do that.

Build another `List` or `Set` with the criteria you are looking for, it's easier and you leave intact the list you were given that, in fact, you don't know if you are going to need it further (or not).

**UPDATE**

Have a look at this:

```
final List<String> myList = Lists.newArrayList("NEW ROW", "cs", "1", "2",
    "3", "NEW ROW", "tp", "3", "4", "5"); // Guava's way
final List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
final int TIMES = 2;
int x = 0;

for (String value : myList) {
  if (x > 0) {
    x--;
  } else {
    if ("NEW ROW".equals(value)) {
      x = TIMES;
    } else {
      result.add(value);
    }
  }
}
System.out.printf("%s%n", result);
```

Comment: Although building another list is often a good choice, there are situations when it's too wasteful. For example, if you need to keep most of the elements in a large list, and you need to do it in a tight loop, modifying the data structure in place may give you a large improvement in timing.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, create an empty `List` and fill it with the elements you don't want to remove.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The operation will be `O(N)` (or worst if we take some other criteria) anyway, so I can't find a single reason why modifying something that somebody gave me it's a good choice. Moreover, deleting from a data structure is expensive (please, don't try to sell me the `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` plethora).

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ You are right about the linked vs. array list implementation. Array list lets you do removals in place in a single path through the list by moving the data you wish to keep to the front and deleting the rest of the list.